# Is there a better way to get the difference of 2 lists in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

For 2 lists of string `s` and `t`, I'd like to get the members of s not in t. Within each list, there are no duplicates.

In Python, I'd use `s.difference(t)`

Is there a similarly concise .NET method? I'd like to avoid using a loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx).

```
Dim difference = s.Except(t)
```

Comment: Yep, just include the `System.Linq` namespace and you're on your way with `Except` and all kinds of Linq goodness.

Comment: Just be aware that difference will be an `IEnumerable(Of String)` in this case. You can use `.ToList()` if you wish it to return a list instead.